# Attribute error response object doesnot have an attribute 'text'

Tags: python, scrapy, attributeerror

I am trying to use python scrapy tool for extracting the information from the bitcointalk.org website about the users and the public keys that they post in the forum for donation.

I found this piece of code online, made changes to it so that it runs on my desired website, but I am running into an error AttributeError response object has no attribute text.

Below is the code for reference

```
class BitcointalkSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "bitcointalk"
allowed_domains = ["bitcointalk.org"]

start_urls = ["https://bitcointalk.org/index.php"]

rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(deny=[
        'https://bitcointalk\.org/index\.php\?action=ignore',
        'https://bitcointalk\.org/index\.php\?action=profile',
        ], 
        allow_domains='bitcointalk.org'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
)

def parse_item(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//tr[contains(@class, "td_headerandpost")]')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = BitcoinItem()
        item["membername"] = site.xpath('.//td[@class="poster_info"]/b/a/text()').extract()
        addresses = site.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "signature")]/text()').re(r'(1[1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{26,33})')
        if item["membername"] and addresses:
            addr_list = set()
            for addr in addresses:
                if (bcv.check_bc(addr)):
                    addr_list.add(addr)
            item["address"] = addr_list
            if len(addr_list) > 0:
                items.append(item)
    return items
```

and the error that I am receiving is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line     102, in iter_errback
yield next(it)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
for x in result:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py", line 72, in _parse_response
cb_res = callback(response, **cb_kwargs) or ()
File "/home/sunil/Desktop/Nikhil/Thesis/mit_bitcoin/bitcoin/spiders/bitcointalk_spider.py", line 24, in parse_item
sel = Selector(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/selector/unified.py", line 63, in __init__
text = response.text
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is likely wrong with one of your requests, since it seems like the response from at least one url your crawling is not properly formatted. Either the request itself failed, or you're not making requests appropriately.

[See here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/selector/unified.py#L63) for the source of your error.

And [see here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#constructing-selectors) for a clue as to why your request may be poorly formatted. It looks like `Selector` expects an `HtmlResponse` object, or a similar type.